# Flutter AppBar has extra space above

Tags: android, ios, flutter, appbar

First, have a look at the image of the app bar with the extra space above the Title (just ignore the text red color).
[image: AppBar]

Secondly following is my code:

```
caffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          titleSpacing: 10,
          centerTitle: false,

          title: Text(
            'Profile',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
          ),

          // toolbarHeight: 10,

          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          // flexibleSpace: Align(
          //   alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          //   child: Container(
          //       width: double.infinity,
          //       margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          //       child: Row(
          //         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          //         children: [
          //           Text(
          //             'Profile',
          //             style: TextStyle(
          //                 fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          //           ),
          //           Align(
          //             alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          //             child: Visibility(
          //               child: Container(
          //                 height: 100,
          //                 margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, top: 0.0),
          //                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
          //                 child: IconButton(
          //                     icon: Icon(
          //                       Icons.close,
          //                       color:
          //                           isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black87,
          //                       size: 25,
          //                     ),
          //                     onPressed: () {
          //                       setState(() {
          //                         editCheck = false;
          //                         showClose = false;
          //                       });
          //                     }),
          //               ),
          //               visible: showClose,
          //             ),
          //           ),
          //         ],
          //       )),
          // ),

          actions: [
            Visibility(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, top: 0.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black87,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        editCheck = false;
                        showClose = false;
                      });
                    }),
              ),
              visible: showClose,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Now comes the real problem that as you can see I have commented out the FlexibleSpace code as this code works but the close button "X" in the FlexibleSpace doesn't work in iOS but it works fine in Android. So help me in removing this extra space above the title.

Thanks

Comment: how about wrapping scaffold with safeArea?

Comment: I have done that too but still it doesn't work

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I don't know how but the safeArea is working now.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh could you answer the question(same as comment) so it can be marked as solved (and you get the rep too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your `scaffold` with `SafeArea`.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body:
```

Answer (score 0):

In my web application, the Browser was set to always show bookmark bar. While debugging the Flutter app there was always a space of 76 px above the App bar. In the browser View menu, disabled the 'Always Show Bookmark Bar' option and the space was removed.